# I cannot select Java web for creating Web application What to do now?

Tags: java, web, netbeans, web-application

Netbeans 8.1 JDK 1.8 
cannot create web application project as shown in screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the right plugin installed:

1. Go to the *Tools* menu and select *Plugins*
2. Click on the "Available Plugins" tab
3. Check the box for "Java EE Base"
   (on older NetBeans versions the plugin is called "Java Web Applications")
4. Click the "Install" button.
5. Click through the dialogs until the plugin and all its dependencies are installed
6. Restart the IDE.

You should now find "Java Web" in *File > New Project*.

Alternatively, when you download Netbeans you have the option to choose the appropriate package for yourself. You can select the package that includes Java Web and EE which comes with Tomcat 6 and GlassFish server.

Comment: Java EE not available!

Comment: Do you have anything that has "Java" in its name?

Comment: I've installed netbeans 8.2 deleted 8.1 and problem solved.

Comment: Good - some parameter was missing during the previous installation, or it was a wrong version of Netbeans.